# How to create ctrl map in command directly?

Tags: key-bindings, command

I'm trying to toggle some ctrl maps in command directly, it didn't work as expected:

```
com Test0 nnoremap <c-j> :echo "c-j"<cr>
com Test1 nnoremap <c-h> :echo "c-h"<cr>
com Test2 exe 'nnoremap <c-l> :echo "c-l"<cr>'
com Test3 exe 'nnoremap <c-right> :echo "c-right"<cr>'

" uncomment this, I see results of :map and "E15: invalid expression: ^M"
" Test0
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Only `Test1` and `Test2` works. 
`Test0` works like `:map`, have no idea why that happens.
If I execute the `exe ...` or `nnoremap ...` sub command in command line, everything works. what am I missing?

Comment: My general advice (also in 'autocmd's) is to avoid all substitution and quoting pitfalls by having your command just call a function and have the function execute all the commands, which means the commands will all run in a sane context where you know what to expect. Also, bonus: you get to add more commands to the function easily rather than having to deal with `|` and `<bar>` etc. (essentially one more variation of the same problem.)

Comment: @filbranden One size does not fit all. There are times the sub command took only one or two statements. I believe one should not write function in that case, especially when that function is only called by this command alone.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. This is interesting. Here's what get saved as the command (`:com Test0`):

```
nnoremap <NL> :echom "c-j"<CR>
```

(`<C-J>` is equivalent to `<NL>` in Vim)

So what do we know about the `<>` format? That it can be used in mappings and abbreviations as a substitute for the represented keys/chars. That it can be used in `exe` command arguments the same way but only if escaped (e.g. `\<Tab>`).

If that command is entered directly it works. It would make sense that it should do the same when run by the operation generated by `com`. But it doesn't. Instead the `<NL>` is acting like Enter key and when `Test0` is run it submits the `nnoremap` alone, immediately. And, actually, we can't assume that something executed indirectly follows the exact same documented behavior as for the directly entered equivalent and obviously it's not here.

Without diving into the code (which I might just do) I can only surmise. There *is* something that makes `<NL>` different from other key(codes). Along with `<CR>` it is the only thing that can submit commands for execution (`:h c_<NL>`: "start entered command"). I'd assume that's a crucial detail here with respect to why other special keycodes (e.g. `<c-h>`) don't behave differently than expected. Note that if you skim through the results of, for example, `:helpgrep <NL>` you'll see there are various places where `<CR>` and `<NL>` have exceptional behavior and/or are treated differently than most other special characters. So I don't think what we're seeing here, while a head-scratcher, is totally unexpected or unprecedented.

Anyways, for now I at least can offer a working version. This successfully escapes the mapped key...

```
com! Test0 exe 'nnoremap \<c-j> :echom "c-j"<cr>'
```

Funny things is, this just adds to the mystery, really. Now we're sort of doing double indirection/interpretation and it works the way we'd expect! Interesting.

Comment: Thanks. I thought keycodes only have special meaning in `map` family commands, I must be wrong. Could you point me where can I find `keycode have special meaning in command` in `help`?

Comment: There is also `:h c_CTRL-H` and `:h c_CTRL-L`, why would `Test1` and `Test2` work? `<c-right>` also have special meaning in command line mode.

Comment: Yeah...the order things are happening is a little different than what I said I believe...updating my answer

Comment: Alas, I retracted my definitive analysis for something less satisfying. :)

Comment: Could be a bug. Could be a necessary compromise. Knowing a little bit about parsers I can envision a scenario where something like `<c-h>` would both do its action but still be picked up as a legal mapping character, too. Their actions (moving the cursor) don't have much impact on things in this scenario but command submission (!) absolutely still could.

Comment: Thanks for the digging. It's the first time I see the valid use  of `\<c-..>` in `single qutoe`, it's so hard to swallow. Another work around is `com! Test0 nnoremap <lt>c-j> :echom "c-j"<cr>`.

Comment: Yeah when you mix quoting and indirect execution you can often throw logic or common sense right out the window (see: Bash). :)