# Why isn't this implemented by default in vim? (line by line Scroll)

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling, navigation

Very often, my preferred way of navigating a file in vim is by "scrolling" line by line. By scrolling, I mean shifting the lines up/down while keeping the cursor on the same line and position. `<c-d>` and `<c-u>` implement this already, but they do so for half a page, not one line.

So I made bindings that implement what I need:

`noremap K k<c-y>` (technically I have `noremap K @='k<C-Y>'<CR>` to accept a count)

`noremap J j<c-e>` (technically I have `noremap J @="j\<lt>C-E>"<CR>` to accept a count)

So hitting `j` and `k` move the cursor up/down one line, and `J` and `K` scroll up/down one line.

But I've learned that vim bindings are made very intelligently. For example, I was always annoyed that searching using `/<term>` and `?<term>` highlight the term and automatically make the cursor jump to the next/previous occurrence of it. I initially wanted them to just highlight the terms and *then* optionally choose to jump to them by hitting `n`, so as not to reset my view if the term doesn't exist in the current view. But I soon found myself using these search methods not necessarily to *search* for these terms, but to actually *jump* to them, as a way of fast navigation. I.e. it is sometimes much faster to search and jump to a pattern to navigate to a line position than by manually moving the cursor (using default movements) to the desired position at a line and position, even if that position is currently in view. And if the term doesn't exist in the current view, I can just call `<c-o>` to reset the view back to where I was.

So is there a reason why line by line scroll isn't implemented by default? I suspect that by making a macro for scrolling, I might be using vim not the way it is intended to be used/not in the most efficient way.

**Edit**: in terms of the scrolling functionality itself, I think the mappings above implements it fairly well and are convenient to use for my purposes. 
**Edit1**: I just found out that in Tmux `copy-mode` with vi bindings enabled, i.e. `set-window-option -g mode-keys vi`, they do implement scrolling the way described above, also using `K` and `J`.

Comment: It's an interesting question though I don't know if it passes the "answers would be primarily opinion based" test barring an appearance by Bram (or Bill Joy?). :) But if Vim's "prime directive" is efficient editing then line-by-line scroll would be a "low priority" movement since that's not how an editing session typically flows. Also, j/k movement which happens without moving the whole set of visible lines is far less jarring to the eye for most people, I would think,  than line-by-line with cursor remaining fixed on one line number. Just two darts thrown at the board. ;)

Comment: When you're browsing a web page, do you read all paragraphs from start of the screen to the end of the screen, then scroll down a page and start reading from start of screen to end of screen? Or do you find yourself reading a few lines, scrolling down a bit, reading a few more lines etc.. such that you typically gaze towards the same area of the screen?

Comment: But that's an application whose primary function is reading. Vim's primary function is editing. Apples and oranges, no? (Regardless, I read the whole thing then scroll in a new page! The less I move things around the easier...for me.)

Comment: Interesting, I do the latter. My gaze usually stays centerish on the screen. Also, you've got to read the text you're editing, right? :)

Comment: Well, as I suggested, opinions could be a big factor here. :)

Comment: I guess use habits, not opinions, right?

Comment: Preferences are cousins of opinions, at least, no?

Comment: Your mappings, although interesting, will behave inconsistently with wrapped lines.

Comment: I could only speculate (of course) but I'd consider two things: 1) Vim was concieved as an improvement of vi, and 2) back in the day vi was designed, it was used over [hardware terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) which could be connected with crappy modem links to the mainframe. Now consider that your style of scrolling forces full screen redraw to move the viewport one line in either direction. On a HW terminal that'd amount to transferring as many bytes as the full screen requires to render (possibly with color codes). …

Comment: …and if you'll look at plain vi (you might install `nvi` on a typical Linux/*BSD-based system to have "full immersion", you'll definitely notice that it has a "make screen updates as scarcily as possible" stance to changing what's displayed on-screen.

Comment: Dont Ctrl-y and Ctrl-e have helpful behavior here?

Comment: @Biggybi Yes I do notice strange behavior at long wrapped lines sometimes. I don't know why that happens. Needs experimenting...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ctrl-y and Ctrl-e are certainly helpful here, but they are hard to reach given the standard typing method of fingers on ```asdf``` and ```jkl;```. But even if they weren't hard to reach, I think I would still prefer to scroll with cursor. I can't point out why, it's subconscious, and might not be optimal.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh It's because Vim scrolls by logical lines, not visual lines (it's a shame there's no way to change that).
As for `<c-e>` and `<c-y>`, they should not be 'hard to reach'. Maybe mapping `caps lock` to `ctrl` in your system might help (`ctrl` is so useful in Vim, it should be easy to reach).

Comment: Personally, I’m of the opinion that the question as stands is too opinion based (“why isnt this feature implemented?”). I’ll refrain from closing until there’s some consensus on that, but in the meantime some [edit]s to change the question to “how do I implement this feature?” would make the question far more suitable for the Q&A model.

Comment: @Biggybi I already map escape to capslock. Im not saying that ctrl is very hard to reach, but compared to other bindings, ctrl-y and ctrl-e are among the hardest. Y is the furthest away from the right index finger in the standard way of typing. And ctrl is the furthest away from the left pinky.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh That's why `ctrl` on `caps lock` is so convenient. It makes everything closer. You can then also escape easily with `ctrl-[`.

Comment: The behavior you're complaining about is pretty much the same as any other common editor, both scrolling and searching. Emacs, Notepad++, Word, etc. Separate control of screen scroll and cursor movement is a feature, letting you decide whether you want to see more context above or below the cursor, and not forcing you to waste screen space at the top or bottom of the buffer.

Comment: Taking your web browser example, web browsers don't usually have cursors. When you're editing a text field and there *is* a cursor, web browsers have separate control of screen scroll and cursor position, just like Vim. I don't know of a single application that ties text cursor repositioning and screen scrolling together.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's true. On all text editors that I know of, the editing cursor itself doesn't move when scrolling. On web browsers, it's not really an editing cursor, but just the mouse's cursor position. However, vim's cursor in normal mode is more similar to a mouse's cursor on the web browser, than the editing cursor in a text editor, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

```
                            *CTRL-D*
CTRL-D          Scroll window Downwards in the buffer.  The number of
            lines comes from the 'scroll' option (default: half a
            screen).  <b>If [count] given, first set 'scroll' option
            to [count].</b>  ...
```

Execute `1<ctrl-d>` for one time, it will set `'scroll'` to 1, you can then use `<c-d>` and `<c-u>` to do line by line scroll without moving cursor.

Comment: The question was about it being "implemented by default". Does this qualify given that the normal function of ctrl-u/ctrl-d is to move half a page? I don't know. :)

Comment: @BLayer I think he just want a builtin way to do it, default or not is not important, everyone has a vimrc, if he set `'scroll'` to 1 in it, it will be default.

Comment: But I want to also have the option of using <c-d/u>. The bindings I made are fine. Just wondering why the functionality isn't implemented by default.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh Run `set scroll&`, you get default hehavior.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh By the way default `J` and `K` are quite useful, see `:h J`, `:h K`.

Comment: That's true, technically you're right then it is available by default. But I'd rather have two separate bindings than having to execute functions to switch between them.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh Then you will need to add a pair of new map to vim and maintain it, too many trivial map is just a  burden.

Comment: @dedowsdi yes, I use the default functionality of ```J``` quite often. So I remapped it to ```<c-j>``` since that binding doesn't do anything/is available. And that's true. But they're only two additional mappings, and honestly, they are indispensable to me at least.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh You can't map `<c-j>`, `<c-j>` is the same as linefeed, it cause problem from time to time (user938271 told me this, I don't buy it until weird problem happens) . It's actually pretty hard to spare a pair of keys to scroll.

Comment: @dedowsdi I don't understand,  ```<c-j>``` just does the same as ```j``` in normal mode. Why would remapping it be a problem? Especially as a non recursive map.

Comment: You should be able to get `<c-j>` mapping working  even if you have to jump through some hoops.... https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23300/how-to-create-ctrl-map-in-command-directly/23301#23301  (and you might not have to...JIC)

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh `<c-j>` is linefeed, I used to use it to select tag from `fzf` and jump between slots in `UltiSnips`,  it doesn't work well, sometimes. Your use case is much simpler, you might can get away with it.

Comment: @BLayer Interesting. This needs some time to read through and understand. But I'm hoping I would be fine with a non recursive ```Ctrl-J``` mapping in normal/visual mode. @dedowsdi, I'm still newish to vim and have no plugins installed, I hope that minimizes risk of conflicts like these.

Comment: @BLayer I'm not wording this correctly, I should say `should not` instead of `can not`. But still, I might be wrong, I throw away `<c-j>` too quickly without diving into `fzf` and `UltiSnips`.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the developer didn't feel that this feature is important enough to deserve a simple key. On the other hand it is possible to create mappings using `1<C-d>` and `1<C-u>` when you need it.

Remember that vi was initially implemented by Billy Joy in 1976. At that time scrolling the screen might have been an expensive operation.

Comment: Oh, come on...  A 300 baud modem can handle almost four lines of text per second...  (Unavoidable for scrolling up on any terminal I actually saw.  Some terminals would help with scrolling down.  Some of this ended up in [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) via [termcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) sourced from `vi`.)